# Substracting two Eloquent result tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

With Eloquent I get two results like this from my db:

```
$deliveries = table1::select('place_id','product_id',DB::raw("SUM(amount) as amount"))->groupBy('place_id', 'product_id');

$purchases = table2::select('place_id','product_id',DB::raw("SUM(quantity) as amount"))->groupBy('place_id', 'product_id');
```

I want to get a table where all the amount entries of table2 are substracted from table1 if

```
place_id from table1 == place_id from table2 
AND 
product_id from table1 == product_id from table2
```

I want to use Eloquent if possible but I am also fine with some raw SQL inside of it or even some fast php-array-method to do something like:

```
$inventory = $deliveries - $purchases;
```

### edited/added

So right now I do this:

```
foreach ($deliveries as $delivery => $delivValue) {
        foreach ($purchases as $purchase => $purchValue) {
            if ($delivValue['place_id']==$purchValue['place_id'] && $delivValue['product_id']==$purchValue['product_id']) {
                $deliveries[$delivery]['amount'] = $delivValue['amount'] - $purchValue['amount'];
            }
        }
    }
```

This works as expected but I think it's very inefficient when the array sizes do increase.

Answer (score 0):

I say this is as close you can get, even if you use laravel's helper method like diff(), etc they still use the same approach internally so your best bet would be to do it at the database level

Try writing this logic at the db level, like

```
DB::select('
    SELECT table1.place_id,table1.product_id,amount,quantity, amount-quantity 
    FROM table1 JOIN table2 
    ON (table1.place_id = table2.place_id 
                  and table1.product_id = table2.product_id)
');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d5775/6/2

used DB::select - assuming you aren't taking any user input